# How to get line breaks with Javascript and VUE

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

In a response from an API I get a plain text that contains line breaks in this way:

**"plain_text": "INFORMACION DEL PRODUCTO:\n\nProducto:**

How can I use these line breaks (\n\n) when printing on WEB page with Javascript (I'm using VUE) ?

Since it only passes the text without the line breaks.

I add image of how it prints with VUE but in the inspector if it appears with the line breaks.

[image: text]

Comment: could you use a `<br>` tag?

Comment: Yes but I get these line breaks from the API call

Comment: @admcfajn you mean to use replace?

Comment: That was my next suggestion, yes

Comment: Here, this looks promising: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784539/how-do-i-replace-all-line-breaks-in-a-string-with-br-tags

Comment: I think vue will not admit that.

Comment: @eag845 It does not work with VUE as you say

Comment: I added an image of how it is printed with VUE but as I can see it with the inspector. I do not understand why in VUE it happens without the line breaks. :/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the CSS [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) property...

```js
const res = {"plain_text": "\t\t\t\tINFORMACION DEL PRODUCTO:\n\nProducto:"}
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: { res }
})
```

```css
.pre-formatted {
  white-space: pre-wrap; /*  this is the important part */
  border: 1px dotted;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <p class="pre-formatted">{{res.plain_text}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @OscarDev I just changed it to `pre-wrap` based on a closer look at your images. This keeps the _indents_ as they appear without collapsing them into a single space character

Answer (score -1):

In html white-spaces are compressed into a single space. 
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782409/why-doesnt-javascript-newlines-work-inside-html) for a similar post.

To have line-breaks in rendered html, you have to manually replace the '\n' with `<br/>` tags.