# How do I create a new line when I use a createelement('p') in JavaScript to HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, newline

I have the following in my JS file:

```
const emailCol = `${email.sender} <br> ${email.subject}  <br>   ${email.timestamp}`
  const moo  = document.createElement('br');
  console.log("HERE!!", emailCol)
  em.innerHTML = emailCol;


  const para = document.createElement("p");
const node = document.createTextNode(`${email.sender} <br></br> `);
para.appendChild(node);
const node1 = document.createTextNode(`${email.timestamp} <br>`);
para.appendChild(node1);
const node2 = document.createTextNode(`${email.subject}</p><p>`);
para.appendChild(node2);
const node3 = document.createTextNode(`${email.body}</p><p>`);
para.appendChild(node3);

const element = document.getElementById("div1");
element.appendChild(para);
```

My aim is to render in HTML something like:

> John@sender.com
>
> jan 10, 2009
>
> subject: happy
>
> body: hello!

However, I am getting this in the webpage:
`John@sender.com <br></br> jan 10, 2009 <br>qww</p><p>body: hello!</p><p>` with no line breaks.

How do I make these breaks become new lines when the webpage renders from JavaScript to HTML?

I tried [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782409/why-doesn-t-javascript-newlines-work-inside-html), but I can't get the `/n` to work.

Comment: `<p>` and `<br>` should create newlines when the HTML is rendered.

Comment: However, even better is to understand that newlines are "just whitespace" in HTML, and use CSS to lay out your content. You don't want newlines. You want HTML elements with classes and attributes that let you  target them with CSS.

Comment: Using append is for created elements in a variable. You are appending a string so it would show a string. You should use innerHTML.

Comment: Thanks everyone. This is super helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createTextNode` is for creating text, not HTML elements like `<br>` or `<p>`.  Try this:

```js
const para1 = document.createElement("p");
para.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${email.sender}`));
para.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
para.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${email.timestamp}`);
para.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
para.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${email.subject}`);

const para2 = document.createElement("p");
para2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`${email.body}`);

const element = document.getElementById("div1");
element.appendChild(para);
element.appendChild(para2);
```