# Create a Line break in the Identity Status Message

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I would like to create a line break in the status message. This is the code I have tried but it wont create a new Line. I am using the Status Message that is used in Identity in Asp.net Razor.

On the cshtml page

```
<partial name="Status Message" model="Model.Status Message" />
```

on the same page I added the following to the scripts

```
 <p style="white-space: pre-line">@Model.StatusMessage</p>
```

on the .cs page

```
if(user.WeeklyReminders  != Input.WeeklyReminders)
{
StatusMessage = "Weekly Reminders email Notifications have been changed. \n";
}
StatusMessage += "Sent";
```

Results is: Weekly Reminders email Notifications have been changed. Sent

I also tried +Enviroment.NewLine(); With the same result.

I want it to be
Weekly Reminders email Notifications have been changed.    
Sent.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782409/why-doesn-t-javascript-newlines-work-inside-html

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Whitespace

Comment: I tried <br> and it posted the <br> in the mesage

Comment: `StatusMessage` should probably be a `HtmlString` I think. I'm a bit rusty with Razor though so I could be mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to realise what was happening and it really bothered me I could not break and debug what was going on.

You are talking about the **Identity** Status Message and it does not use the shared `_StatusMessage.html`, but it has its own version. You first have to [scaffold](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) it (or copy the shared version to `Areas\Identity\Pages\Account\_StatusMessage.cshtml`) before you can edit it.

If you wrap the status message in a `<div>` with the correct `white-space`, it works as expected and the newlines in your string are honoured:

```
@model string

@if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Model))
{
    var statusMessageClass = Model.StartsWith("Error") ? "danger" : "success";
    <div class="alert alert-@statusMessageClass alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
        <div style="white-space: pre-line">@Model</div>
    </div>
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I know of two methods you can try both and see which you understand

```
StatusMessage = "Weekly Reminders email Notifications have been changed. \x0A";
```

or just simply try this

```
StatusMessage = "Weekly Reminders email Notifications have been changed.";
StatusMessage = "\r\n";
StatusMessage = "Sent";
```

Comment: And this makes it render correctly in the resulting HTML for you?

Comment: I dont know what you situation is I cannot test it you have to test it for you self

Comment: Also how is `\x0A` different to `\n`?  [Aren't they the same thing?](https://rextester.com/QKTB4557).

Comment: What does my situation have to do with OP's question? It's OP's question that you're answer is posted on, and OP is using Razor (and the message is therefore being rendered in HTML).

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. The only thing that showed was sent. the StatusMessage = "Weekly Reminders email Notifications have been changed. \x0A"; Showed the message with sent after.